# Specifying a specific file type for ListView interface

Tags: c#, file, explorer, filechooser

I have created a file Explorer in C# to select a file from a list of directories, however I have limited knowledge on how to specify the file type itself.

I only want `.xls` files to be displayed, not all files displayed.  How do I go about this? I currently have:

```
TreeNode newSelected = e.Node;
listView1.Items.Clear();
DirectoryInfo nodeDirInfo = (DirectoryInfo)newSelected.Tag;
ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[] subItems;
ListViewItem item = null;

foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in nodeDirInfo.GetDirectories())
{
    item = new ListViewItem(dir.Name, 0);
    subItems = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]
              {new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "Directory"),
       new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item,
    dir.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString())};
    item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems);
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
foreach (FileInfo file in nodeDirInfo.GetFiles())
{
    item = new ListViewItem(file.Name, 1);
    subItems = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]
              { new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "File"),
       new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item,
    file.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString())};

    item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems);
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your 2nd for loop to:

```
foreach (var file in nodeDirInfo.GetFiles())
{
    if (file.Extension == ".xls")
    {
        // Do the stuff with the file
    }
}
```

or

```
foreach (var file in nodeDirInfo.GetFiles()
    .Where(file => 
        string.Equals(file.Extension, ".xls")))
{
    // Do the stuff with the file
}
```

For your purposes I would recommend using `OpenFileDialog`, as it sounds like you just need the user to select a file from the directory:

```
var openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Path\To\Directory\";
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls)|*.xls";

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    var selectedFilePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
}
```

Comment: @DoN_Dan No problem. May I also suggest that you check out `OpenFileDialog` if this file browser is just for looking at/selecting files within an application

Comment: Thank you - the idea is that I can select a file within a custom UI, with the file opening in the background when selected.  I'll definitely take a look :)

Comment: @DoN_Dan I added a simple example which uses `OpenFileDialog` and includes the `.xls` filter

Answer (score 2):

```
DirectorInfo.GetFiles("*.xls");
```

will give you that filter.

Comment: Thank you - where would I place this piece of code?

Comment: foreach (FileInfo file in nodeDirInfo.GetFiles("*.xls"))